# Metadata migration of documents between sharepoint and salesforce

Tags: sharepoint, salesforce, metadata

I have a requirement to store on the Salesforce front end links to documents that are stored in SharePoint. So a user on Salesforce will click on the document URL and they will be directed to the document in SharePoint.

With this approach can the metadata for the document still be imported into salesforce? if so if you can explain how it would work practically would be appreciated